# Matplotlib : Two treemaps in the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib et squarify and I want to display two distinct treemaps in the same figure.

I use the code below which display the two treemaps in the same axes and i don't get why.

```
http_return_status_label_1 = ['200','300','500']
http_return_status_count_1 =[4,8,12]

http_return_status_label_1 = ['2000','3000','5000']
http_return_status_count_1 =[40,88,102]


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
ax1.subplot = squarify.plot(sizes=http_return_status_count_1, label=http_return_status_label_1, alpha=.8)
ax2.subplot = squarify.plot(sizes=http_return_status_count_2, label=http_return_status_label_2, alpha=.8)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the ax you want to plot to as a kwarg `ax=` (see the [doc](https://github.com/laserson/squarify/tree/master#documentation-for-squarify)). Also, you can disable the axis for each ax:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify

http_return_status_label_1 = ['200','300','500']
http_return_status_count_1 =[4,8,12]

http_return_status_label_2 = ['2000','3000','5000']
http_return_status_count_2 =[40,88,102]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
squarify.plot(sizes=http_return_status_count_1, label=http_return_status_label_1, alpha=.8, ax=ax1)
squarify.plot(sizes=http_return_status_count_2, label=http_return_status_label_2, alpha=.8, ax=ax2)

ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]